# Pyzbar returns extra, incorrect bar codes

Tags: python-2.7, zbar

Using what I believe are the curent stable versions of zbar (0.10) and pyzbar (0.1.8) and a very unambiguous image (below), I receive two Decoded objects (below).

One of them is correct and the other is very close but wrong.

Is this a bug in pyzbar or zbar? How should I report it if so?

I notice that the rect and polygon attributes of the incorrect Decoded image have bogus or missing values. Is this a reliable clue on which I could use to weed out the bogus values?

(MacOS Mojave, zbar installed with HomeBrew)

Correct:

```
Decoded(
    data='10001330100070', 
    type='I25', 
    rect=Rect(left=35, top=79, width=69, height=674), 
    polygon=[
        Point(x=35, y=79), 
        Point(x=36, y=753), 
        Point(x=104, y=753), 
        Point(x=103, y=80), 
        Point(x=99, y=79)]
    )
```

Incorrect:

```
Decoded(
    data='10001330100062', 
    type='I25', 
    rect=Rect(left=33, top=145, width=0, height=0), 
    polygon=[Point(x=33, y=145)]
    )
```

[image: unambigous bar code]